# How to get a party member into a Bag of Holding or Rope Trick to break a Vampire's Charm?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters

As per answers to this question [What can break a Vampire’s Charm besides Greater Restoration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120792/what-can-break-a-vampire-s-charm-besides-greater-restoration/120840#120840) - a vampire's charm can be challenging to break (i.e. Dispel Magic doesn't work) but the charm can potentially be broken by separating the victim and the vampire onto different planes.

Separating a charmed PC onto a different plane might be accomplished by having that PC step into a Bag of Holding or climbing a Rope Trick into an extra-dimensional space. Getting a charmed PC to do this could be challenging. A Bag of Holding is a small space for a humanoid.

Additionally complicating just asking the PC to enter the extra-dimensional space is:

> The Charmed target regards the vampire as a trusted friend to be heeded and protected. Although the target isn't under the vampire's control, it takes the vampire's requests or actions in the most favorable way it can

The vampire could conflict the PC by requesting they do not enter either space.

How would we and what are the guidelines around forcing such a charmed (i.e. potentially unwilling) party member into a Bag of Holding or into the extra-dimensional space created by Rope Trick?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is here. Why can't you just ask the party member to get in? Or force them in? Is there some special challenge to moving a person into one of these things that is unique to being charmed?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Yes, the charmed effect is just the motivation for the desired outcome. The core question is how do you force (a potentially unwilling) PC into a Bag of Holding or to climb a Rope Trick.

Comment: Is there some reason a friend of the party would be inherently unwilling to do so?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Sure, according to the description of the charm, the vampire's requests are taken by the PC in "...the most favorable way it can..." Thus, the vampire could request the PC doesn't enter the space thus creating resistance.

Comment: This question is way too broad as asked. It has potentially an infinite amount of answers to it. Any way to forcibly move, coerce, tempt, enchant, or otherwise locomote another being is an acceptable answer here and that is a very long list of things indeed. And none of those solutions are unique to the condition of being charmed.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are misreading the charmed condition. When an ally is charmed they do not have to obey the vampire. They just cannot take any harmful actions against the vampire until they are no longer charmed so you can just use Rope trick and tell them to climb up.

Should your party member decides to roleplay being charmed and say he is in love with the vampire and he will fight to protect her then you can do the following things:

**Drag Them**

If you have a barbarian or some other class with high strength score you can grab the person who is affected by the charm and drag them to the area created by the rope trick.

**Throw Them**

While this solution may deal damage to your ally it will take far less effort to just throw them inside the area.

**Trick Them**

Assuming your party member is attacking one of your friends just have your friend climb to the rope trick and he will have to follow behind resulting in getting into extradimensional space.

Comment: Vampires have a special ability that does more than subject someone to the "Charmed" condition. As @Praxiteles quoted, on page 297 of the Monster Manual, it states "The charmed target regards the vampire as a trusted friend to be heeded and protected. Although the target isn't under the vampire's control, it takes the vampire's requests or actions in the most favorable way it can, and it is a willing target for the vampire's bite attack."